# fix shrink to fit for IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

While printing one of the pages, the content is zoomed in. This happens in IE8 which seems to be a Shrink to fit issue. This works fine if I render in IE 7 but then many UI elements break. 
Is there a way to fix Shrink to fit issue in IE 8 using CSS or Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Which page? I don't recall IE8 having that problem.

Comment: the page belongs to my website.

Comment: You say "one of the pages" is zoomed in. That means not all of the pages, right? So there is a difference between that page and the other pages?